# Remove drawn faces in Face detection API - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, face-detection

I used following open source code to detect faces in an image.

https://github.com/zhangao0086/iOS-CoreImage-Swift/tree/master/FaceDetection

I select image from camera but when I again want to select a new picture, I want the previous rectangles to be removed since I will run same API again on new image. Although my code finds new faces in new image, but it doesnt override previous UIImage.

How do I remove the previously drawn rectangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [this](https://github.com/zhangao0086/iOS-CoreImage-Swift/blob/master/FaceDetection/FaceDetection/ViewController.swift) view controller you can say something like:

```
for view in self.imageView.subviews
{
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```